# javascript problem setting attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the attribute of an element programmatically, but firebug keeps giving the error: obj.setAttribute is not a function. I'm using jQuery so I'm going to show a bit of extra code so you can see the context.

The code is the following:

```
$j(function(){
  function callback(response) {

        if (response.status == 200) {
            var data = response.responseBody;
            console.log(data)
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var artistData = $j.parseJSON(data);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(artistData.location.lat, artistData.location.lng),
                      map: map
                    });

                var obj =  document.getElementById('ratingRender').firstChild;
                obj.setAttribute("model", "[artist: deftones, rating: 4.0, artistID: 1]");
                document.getElementById('recommendedList').appendChild(obj);
            }
        }
        }

    $j.atmosphere.subscribe('${resource(dir: '/atmosphere/recommend')}',
        callback,
        $j.atmosphere.request = {transport: 'streaming'});

    $j('#buttonPost').click(function() {
        var searchedArtist = '${search.artist}';
        $j.get('${createLink(action: "recommend")}?artist=' + searchedArtist);
    });
});
```

and the ratingRender div:

```
<div id="ratingRender" style="display: none">
    <g:render template="/artist/rate" model="[artist: deftones, rating: 3.0, artistID: 1]" />
</div>
```

Any ideas why is this happening?
Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

I tried with this:

```
var obj =  $('#ratingRender').children().eq(0);
obj.attr("model", "[artist: deftones, rating: 4.0, artistID: 1]");
```

and it doesn't give the error anymore. However, it is not modifying the attribute either. I don't know why. Anyone?

Comment: I think it *might* have to do with the fact that this isn't a valid attribute, nor a valid element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use jquery? try this

```
var obj =  $('#ratingRender').children().eq(0);
obj.attr("model", "[artist: deftones, rating: 4.0, artistID: 1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first child of `ratingRender` is a text node containing only whitespace:

```
var obj =  document.getElementById('ratingRender').firstChild;
obj.setAttribute("model", "[artist: deftones, rating: 4.0, artistID: 1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, why not use... jQuery?

```
var obj = $("#ratingRender").children().first();
obj.attr("model", "[artist: deftones, rating: 4.0, artistID: 1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your firstChild is whitespace. Explanation on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.firstChild)

Answer (score 0):

Mixing the native APIs with jQuery APIs when you are doing DOM manipulation will only get you into trouble. jQuery uses wrappers to allow you to manipulate the DOM, so you shouldn't need to do setAttribute. Instead, use jQuery's  `attr` method.